# how to add a css style property dynamically in JSF

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I am using primeface for the UI components and I have to set the background of the layout unit temporary its done by using the css style,

```
 .layoutCustomStyle.ui-layout-unit-content
  {
     background-image: url('resources/images/backgrnd.png');
  }
```

The id of the layoutunit is "layoutId" and the styleclass used is "layoutCustomStyle"

in xhtml,

```
<p:layoutUnit position="top" id= "layoutId" styleClass ="layoutCustomStyle">
</p:layoutUnit>
```

But what I want is to add the background image dynamically. The image will be chosen by file browser so, I cannot add a separate class for that and use bean.

```
UIViewRoot view = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
UIComponent comp= view.findComponent("layoutId");
Map<String, Object> attrMap = comp.getAttributes();
String className = (String)attrMap.get("styleClass");
```

using this I can set and get class names but how to change the attribute  "background-image:" dynamically?

Hope the question is clear.Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Pegasus

Comment: Dynamically mean on what EVENT you want to change backgrounds??Are you using any Bean class?? I you tell me correctly then I'll provide the code for you.

Comment: There is a file browser and the chosen image should be set as the background. Yes I am using bean class.I am using primeface fileupload component for choosing the image file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `style` attribute instead of `styleClass`.

Comment: I added style "background-image:url("")" dynamically. But on calling "update" the layoutunit disappears(it moves some where up near header layout unit and is hidden). its the problem with "update"

Comment: Just use `style="#{bean.style}"` instead where `#{bean}` is a view scoped bean. Manually grabbing components and directly manipulating them programmatically has always been a fishy way.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but at this time has been viewed 10,354 times. I want to share the way i resolve 'add a css style property dynamically' in primefaces 6.2

In my layout i have a header that i need change dyamically the image every 10|20 secs.

```
 <h:panelGrid id="cabecera" columns="2" cellpadding="1" columnClasses="..."   
       style="width:100%; background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-image: url('#{request.contextPath}/resources/images/header/Vignette/#{userSelected.headerFile}');">    
            <h:form id="...."  >
```

I have a list with the names of all the images that i can use and **userSelected.headerFile** choose one randomly.

Three similar options:

1.- At first i Use **p:poll** directly to update the **panelGrid** id **'cabecera'**:

```
<p:poll interval="10" update="@([id$=cabecera])" autoStart="true"/>
```

Of course that works, on every update the *background image* change. That could be enough in some cases where the update and page blink don´t be problem.

2.- Using a little of JavaScript, a bean method in the listener of **p:poll**. 
    Declare a js function to change the *background property* (or any other):

```
 <script> 
     function headerBackground(urlBG) {
         var laUrl =  (urlBG); 
         document.getElementById('cabecera').style.backgroundImage = laUrl;
     }
 </script>
```

In my Bean **userSelected** i declared *a method to call the javascript* function via **RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(...)**. I decided received the **url only** and add the rest of values in the function:

```
public void callJSheaderBackground(String url) {
    String jsFunc="headerBackground(\"".concat(url.trim()).concat("\")");
    try{
        RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();  
        requestContext.execute(jsFunc);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally the **p:poll**

```
  <p:poll interval="20"  listener="#{userSelected.callJSheaderBackground('url(\''.concat(request.contextPath).concat('/resources/images/header/Vignette/').concat(userSelected.headerFile).concat('\')'))}"  autoStart="true"/>
```

3.- Calling directly a JS function 
My JS function, reciving the **contextPath** and the **image file name** as parameters:

```
 function setVignetteAsBackground(contextPath,vignetteName) {
     var laUrl =  "url('" + (contextPath)+'/resources/images/header/Vignette/'+(vignetteName)+"')";  
     document.getElementById('cabecera').style.backgroundImage = laUrl;
 }
```

Then directly calling from **p:poll** on the *onstart*|*oncomplete* event:

```
<p:poll interval="20" onstart="setVignetteAsBackground('#{request.contextPath}','#{userSelected.headerFile}')"  autoStart="true"/>
```

Hopefully be useful for somebody.